# How to adjust aspect ratio and resolution in tokbox

Tags: webrtc, opentok

I've created a simple WebRTC chat app using tokbox / opentok 2.0.

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to make sure that the video appears in a 16.9 aspect ratio. The default on most systems is 4.3, and on my MacBook Pro, I am getting 16.9 squished into a 4.3 box.

Is there an api call I am missing to force a widescreen aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the aspect ratio on TokBox's API, although you can set the width and height properties when you call initPublisher or session.subscribe(). It says in the [documentation](http://tokbox.com/opentok/v1/libraries/client/js/reference/Session.html):

> If the width and height of the display do not match the 4:3 aspect ratio of the video signal, the video stream is cropped to fit the display.